# mail alert is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am trying ti set a form in my contact page,where the user can send their feedback to me through mails. The problem here is am receiving the mail,but the page is not refreshing and no alert box comes...help to solve this
My Php code-

```
 <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
            //print_r($_POST);
$name=$_POST['name'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$message=$_POST['message'];


$to='xyz@gmail.com';         
//$subject='Send mail using php';
//$message='This mail send using php';
$headers="From: $name";
$mail=mail($to,$name,$email,$message);
if($mail)
{
 echo'Mail send successfully';
}
else
{
 echo'Mail is not send';
}}

?>
```

and my form is-

```
    <form name="" action="" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label>Your Name</label><br />
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" placeholder="Your name..." />
    </div>
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <label>Phone</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" placeholder="Phone number..." />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <label>Email Address</label><br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" placeholder="Email Address..." />
    </div>


</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Message</label><br />
    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit submit_btn" />


</form>
```

Comment: have you used any jquery or javascript also?

Comment: no i did't use those @rohit

Comment: code is working, refreshing also and with message

Comment: also mail will be mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: its not working for me @rahesh...is there any other problem

Comment: Why should there be an alert? There's no call to Javascript `alert()`.

Comment: hi Barmar..could you specify me any links to implement this using javascripts...

Comment: may be you are using contact form 7 in wordpress, right because your form class look like contact form 7

Comment: This php and form are on the same page correct? PHP at the top and form at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the message displayed as an alert, you can do:

```
$mail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
?>
<script>
alert('<?php echo $mail ? "Mail sent successfully" : "Mail was not sent" ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: when i insert your script,the contact.php page itself dissapperas..a blank page comes

Comment: The default action for a form is the page's URL.

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, maybe there's an error. Check your PHP error log.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function

```
$mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
```

If you want to create alert change code as below.

```
$mail=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($mail)
{
?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>alert("Mail sent");</script>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
   <script type='text/javascript'>alert("Mail is not send");</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: he said he's receiving the mail correctly. So maybe that was a copying error?

Answer (score 0):

for js alert check below code

```
if($mail)
{
 echo'<script>alert("Mail send successfully");</script>';
}
```